# Why does speech synthesizer can output to 3gp when it is documented as wav?

Tags: android

Android's speech synthesizer (`TextToSpeech.synthesizeToFile`) is supposed to output files in wav format. I specified "/sdcard/.../file.3gp" and yet, I can play it. Why ?

Comment: Maybe the player is smart enough to figure out the file type from the file contents? Naming a file ".3gp" doesn't make it a 3GP file.

Comment: If you open your "3gp" file in a binary file editor, you'll probably see "RIFF WAV" in the first bytes.